# Phasors Diagram Software

Tags: software, diagram, phasor

I've searched the Net to find a decent software that would give me phasors plots with stacked phasors (for adding , subtracting phasors etc), such as the image below, but I couldn't find it. I tried in Matlab sofware but nothing fits my problem.
[image]

Does anyone of you has a suggested software for my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/search/perform/search/phasor) is definetively what you need.

Comment: Matlab would do this just fine, but it requires some effort. If you simply want to draw them then use illustrator, visio or powerpoint